# Emails declined because of helo localhost

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

I'm stuck on configuring smtp settings in magento 2 2.3.5-p1.

I'm using mageplaza smtp plugin - everythings fine here. The emails are sent correctly but are declined by other hosters because of the helo / ehlo entry 'localhost'.

Where did this come from and how can i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who may stumble about weird error messsages like:

"Emails rejected: 554-Reject due to policy restrictions"

Try searching for errors in more obvious places instead of making complex SPF-Entries, checking blacklists or looking for helo / ehlo entries to be perfect.

In my case the sender-name of the email contains a ":" - doublepoint.
Example "John Smith: Consultant"

It's not allowed to use ":" in sender-name when mailing to specific hoster.

Hope it helps and saves time..